# Realmスキーマ変更に伴うクラッシュについて

Tags: android, realm

Androidアプリの開発において、Realmまわりでクラッシュが発生しております。

Realmファイルは下記の時系列で生成、変更を行いました。

- α版

  - デフォルトRealmのみを使用
- β版

  - RealmModuleを使用して、デフォルトRealmと別のRealmの2つに分割
  - デフォルトRealm側のとあるモデルクラスにて、一部のプロパティを "Date" から "String" へ変更

β版のテスト時ではクラッシュが無いことを確認したため、そのままβ版を製品版としてリリース致しました。
（α版については内部テストのみに使用したものであり、リリースはしておりません）

### 発生した事象

- リリース直後から、下記のエラーログが出力される多数のクラッシュを検知（クラッシュ率は全体のダウンロード数の約16%）
- Google Playから製品版をテスト用端末へインストールしたが、クラッシュが発生しないことを確認
- α版がインストールされている端末に製品版をアップデートしたところ、下記と同様のエラーログが出力されクラッシュが発生することを確認

---

### 当該エラーログ

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxx}: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Invalid type 'String' for field 'notifyAt' in existing Realm file.
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2482)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2545)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:186)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1410)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5636)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
Caused by io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Invalid type 'String' for field 'notifyAt' in existing Realm file.
   at io.realm.ChildNotificationEntityRealmProxy.validateTable(ChildNotificationEntityRealmProxy.java:270)
   at io.realm.DefaultModuleMediator.validateTable(DefaultModuleMediator.java:83)
   at io.realm.Realm.initializeRealm(Realm.java:342)
   at io.realm.Realm.createAndValidate(Realm.java:299)
   at io.realm.Realm.createInstance(Realm.java:278)
   at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:143)
   at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java:209)
   at (appname).models.ChildModel.findById(ChildModel.java:56)
   at (appname).models.UserModel.getCurrentChild(UserModel.java:30)
   at (appname).activities.LaunchActivity.sendLaunchScreen(LaunchActivity.java:70)
   at (appname).activities.LaunchActivity.onCreate(LaunchActivity.java:39)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6315)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2435)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2545)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:186)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1410)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5636)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

### 備考

- テスト用の実機端末

  - Xperia Z5, Android 6.0
  - Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1
  - Galaxy S3α, Android 4.3
- クラッシュしている端末、OS情報（Crashlyticsからの情報）

  - Sony端末が60%、その他が40%
  - OS情報

    - 6.0が50%
    - 4.0, 5.0が20%ずつ
    - 7.0が10%

お手数ですが、ご教示お願い致します。

---

2017/02/23
追加情報

## マイグレーション処理

```
import android.util.Log;
import io.realm.DynamicRealm;
import io.realm.RealmMigration;
import io.realm.RealmSchema;

public class Migration implements RealmMigration {
    private static final String TAG = Migration.class.getName();

    @Override
    public void migrate(final DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        Log.d(TAG, "realm migration version:" + String.valueOf(oldVersion));
        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
    }
}
```

### Realm設定部分

```
private static RealmConfiguration mDefaultConfig;
private static RealmConfiguration mReadOnlyConfig;

@RealmModule(classes = {
        ChildArticleEntity.class,
        ChildEntity.class,
        ChildNotificationEntity.class,
        FavoriteArticleEntity.class,
        ReadArticleEntity.class
})
public static class DefaultModule {
}

@RealmModule(classes = {
        ArticleEntity.class,
        CategoryEntity.class,
        DateEventEntity.class,
        DaysOldEventEntity.class,
        DaysOldNotificationEntity.class,
        MonthsOldEventEntity.class,
        MonthsOldNotificationEntity.class,
        SuggestSearchWordEntity.class,
        TimelineEntity.class
})
public static class ReadOnlyModule {
}

public static void setupDefaultRealm() {
    if (mDefaultConfig == null) {
        mDefaultConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .schemaVersion(CURRENT_SCHEME_VERSION)
                .migration(new Migration())
                .modules(new DefaultModule())
                .build();
    }
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(mDefaultConfig);
}

public static Realm getReadonlyInstance() {
    if (mReadOnlyConfig == null) {
        mReadOnlyConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name(READ_ONLY_FILE_NAME)
                .schemaVersion(CURRENT_SCHEME_VERSION)
                .migration(new Migration())
                .modules(new ReadOnlyModule())
                .build();
    }
    return Realm.getInstance(mReadOnlyConfig);
}
```

### スキーマ

```
import java.util.Date;

import io.realm.RealmObject;

public class ChildNotificationEntity extends RealmObject {
    private int childId;
    private String message;
    private String notifyAt;

    public int getChildId() {
        return childId;
    }

    public void setChildId(int childId) {
        this.childId = childId;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getNotifyAt() {
        return notifyAt;
    }

    public void setNotifyAt(String notifyAt) {
        this.notifyAt = notifyAt;
    }
}
```

### あらかじめ作成したrealmファイルをアプリケーションに読み込む処理

```
public static void importReadonlyRealmIfNeeded(Context context) {
    try {
        //端末内保持バージョン
        SharedPreferences s = context.getSharedPreferences(AppConst.PACKAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int versionCode = s.getInt(KEY_VERSION_CODE, 0);

        //現在のビルドバージョン
        PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        int currentVersionCode = pInfo.versionCode;

        //version codeがアップデートされるとインポートが走る
        if (versionCode == currentVersionCode) {
            Log.i("realm", "import skip");
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Copy readonly.realm to this device");
        copyBundledRealmFile(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.readonly), READ_ONLY_FILE_NAME, context);

        s.edit().putInt(KEY_VERSION_CODE, currentVersionCode).apply();
        Log.i("realm", "success import");

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void copyBundledRealmFile(InputStream inputStream, String outFileName, Context context) {
    try {
        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), outFileName);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: エラーメッセージに`Invalid type 'String' for field 'notifyAt'`と書かれているので、「一部のプロパティを "Date" から "String" へ変更」が原因でしょう。マイグレーションが不完全なのだと思います。モデルやマイグレーション、インスタンス化部分のコードを見せられませんか？モジュールにスキーマを分けたつもりで２つのRealmで共有していませんか？

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi 
ご回答頂きましてありがとうございます。
今回の問題に関わると思われる処理を質問本文へ追記致しました。
Realmファイルの共有につきましては、adbコマンドで端末内部の2つのRealmファイル取得し、当該スキーマがデフォルトRealmのみに存在することを確認致しました。
デフォルトRealmから分割した読み込み専用Realmファイルは、スキーマ変更時に再作成し Android Stdio へ組み込み、アプリ起動時にそれを読み込む処理を行っています。
お手数ですがご確認よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi 
お世話になっております。
上記の件につきまして、Migrationの対応を行うことに致しました。
notifyAtを削除し、新しいString型のプロパティを追加します。
もし本対応につきましてご意見等ございましたらコメント頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: それは問題の解決にならないように思えますが、Realmマイグレーションがどういうものかは理解していますでしょうか？

Comment: Realmファイルの扱いについて、開発中はスキーマの変更があった場合、Realmファイル(ver0)は一旦削除した後に再作成をしておりました。
しかし、今回の件についてはRealmファイルの再作成によって解決に至らなかったため、「ver0」のスキーマは許容して、Migrationによって解決をしようと考えております。

Comment: 起こっているのはマイグレーションのエラーなので効果はあるとは思いますが、ちゃんとファイルが消えてるならそもそもマイグレーションの問題は起こらないので、何が起こってるのかをちゃんと突き止めたほうが良いかと思います。

Comment: 色々と調査した結果、リリース中のアプリのマイグレーションのoldVersionが0ではなく1になっていることが判明しました。結果として型をDateからStringへ移行するマイグレーションの処理を記述し解決致しました。色々とご助言頂きありがとうございました。
しかし、oldVersionをインクリメントする処理はこれまで記述していなかったため、どのタイミングでマイグレーションのバージョンが上がったのか、まだ原因は掴めていない状況です。

Comment: 提示されたコードを見ると`.schemaVersion(CURRENT_SCHEME_VERSION)`と両方のRealmについて指定してますけど、これが間違いではないのですか？
それぞれ違うRealmに対して同じスキーマバージョンを指定するというのは、変だと思うのですが。空のマイグレーションなど、もっと変なところがあるので、先にそちらを聞きましたが、この処理もだいぶおかしく見えます。

Comment: ご連絡遅くなり申し訳ございません。
おっしゃる通り、両Realmにおいて同じschemaVersionを指定していたところに問題がありました。それぞれのRealmに対して該当するschemaVersionを設定、Migrationを別々の処理に変更してリリース致しましたが、現在エラーが発生していないことを確認しております。

Answer (score 1):

マイグレーションの処理が何も記述されていないように見えます。

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/v2.3.1/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/model/Migration.java#L114

に、フィールドの型をStringからintに変更する例があるので、これを参考に `notifyAt` を `Date` から `String` へ移行する処理を記述してください。

Comment: ご回答頂きましてありがとうございました。
頂いたURLを参考にマイグレーション処理を記述し問題が解決致しました。またrealmまわりで何かありましたらお力添えをいただきますよう、お願いいたします。